# Auto search after barcode/qrcode scanner update values into input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I manually input values into input it triggers the search with on('keyup') method. What I actually want is when I scan the barcode/qrcode with my phone camera (manage to scan and pass the values into input) to trigger auto search without me having to press into input and manually trigger.

Btw after scanning, the input has no focus like when you first load the page.

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="barcode-value" value="" class="qrcode-text" tabindex="-1">
<label class=qrcode-text-btn>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" onchange="openQRCamera(this);" tabindex="-1">  
</label>
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout;
    var $element = null;

    $('form[name="barcodes-form"]').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('input[name="barcode-value"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
      $element = $(this);
      timeout = setTimeout(search_barcode, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: you can manually trigger it, in the function where you update input by bar-code

Comment: Yes I can, but I wrote I want without me having to press and trigger it

Comment: have you tried change instead of keyup, or both 'change keyup' .

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: `Yes I can, but I wrote I want without me having to press and trigger it` not possible. Events are not raised when you programmatically change the value of an input. You *have* to do it manually.

Comment: Hmhm, I thought it can be done by this logic : after scan and passing values bring back focus to input and trigger search with function something like Val>4. Or without focus, just check if there are val>4 to trigger